# Changing the button name without changing all buttons names

Tags: reactjs

I have a button `Name`, by clicking on it the name changes to `Stop`. For this I am just using `useState` where passing false/true when it's clicked. Everything works well, but if I add another button and click on it, the name of all buttons change to `Stop`. How to prevent this action and change only the name of clicked button?

```
const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false)

function playName(){
   setIsPlaying(!isPlaying)
........
}

function playAge(){
   setIsPlaying(!isPlaying)
........
}
return(
<div>
<button
  id="btnName"
  onClick={playName}
  type="button">
  {isPlaying ? 'Stop' : 'Name'}
</button>
<button
  id="btnAge"
  onClick={playAge}
  type="button">
  {isPlaying ? 'Stop' : 'Age'}
</button>
</div>
)
```

Comment: can u put it on github or sandbox and maybe i will solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use only one single boolean value to control multiple buttons' states, which is absolutely impossible.

One way to achieve this is to have a state storing the name of the button that is playing.

Try something like this:

```js
const [playingBtnName, setPlayingBtnName] = useState('')

function playName(){
   setPlayingBtnName('name')
........
}

function playAge(){
   setPlayingBtnName('age')
........
}
return(
<div>
<button
  id="btnName"
  onClick={playName}
  type="button">
  {playingBtnName === 'name' ? 'Stop' : 'Name'}
</button>
<button
  id="btnAge"
  onClick={playAge}
  type="button">
  {playingBtnName === 'age' ? 'Stop' : 'Age'}
</button>
</div>
)
```

The way above does not allow two buttons playing at the same time. If you want multiple buttons be be playing at the same time, you can use an array to store all those names playing:

```js
const [playingBtnNames, setPlayingBtnNames] = useState([])

function playName(){
   setPlayingBtnNames([...playingBtnNames, 'name'])
........
}

function playAge(){
   setPlayingBtnNames([...playingBtnNames, 'age'])
........
}
return(
<div>
<button
  id="btnName"
  onClick={playName}
  type="button">
  {playingBtnNames.includes('name') ? 'Stop' : 'Name'}
</button>
<button
  id="btnAge"
  onClick={playAge}
  type="button">
  {playingBtnNames.includes('age') ? 'Stop' : 'Age'}
</button>
</div>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false)


function playName(event){
   setIsPlaying(e.event.target)
........
}

function playAge(event){
   setIsPlaying(e.event.target)
........
}
return(
<div>
<button
  id="btnName"
  onClick={playName}
  type="button">
  {isPlaying === false ? 'Stop' : 'Name'}
</button>
<button
  id="btnAge"
  onClick={playAge}
  type="button">
  {isPlaying === false ? 'Stop' : 'Age'}
</button>
</div>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for you:

```js
const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false)

function playName(){
   setIsPlaying(true)
........
}

function playAge(){
   setIsPlaying(true)
........
}

if(isPlaying){
return(
<div>
<button id="btnName"
  onClick={()=>{return;}}
  type="button">
Stop
</button>
<button
  id="btnAge"
  onClick={()=>{return}}
  type="button">
Stop
</button>
</div>
)}
return(
<div>
<button>
<button id="btnName"
  onClick={()=>{return;}}
  type="button">
Name
</button>
<button
  id="btnAge"
  onClick={()=>{return}}
  type="button">
Age
</button>
</button>
</div>
)
```

What I changed:

I switched what you did(Changing the button's name by making a direct comparison) and made it conditional rendering. This approach is better because every time you change/update the state react will rerender the component and make the condition true. If this does not work, I think it's most likely that you have a problem with your other code. Make sure to have a good look at it if that happens.

I Hope This helps you!

PS: Sorry if your code is a little messed up

Answer (score 1):

you need to use separate variables for this. but it is not recommended.

since using single variable results in changing all button property.

you can use object of Boolean values to store all the button properties

refer:

https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-sun-isjzyl?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

The solutions provided dont seem a scalable one, perhaps you could find this a more viable option for a long term usage

```
const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState([false,false])
const [buttonNames,setButtonNames] = useState([{name:'Name'},{name:"Age"}]);
const onClickPlayButton=(index)=>{
  setIsPlaying(isPlaying.map((e,_i)=>_i==index?!e:e));
}
<button id="btnName"
  onClick={()=> setIsPlaying(isPlaying.map((e)=>false))}
  type="button">
Stop
</button>
{buttonNames.map((e,_idx)=><button
  id="btnAge"
  onClick={()=> onClickPlayButton(_idx)}
  type="button">{isPlaying[index]?e.name:'STOP'}
</button>)}
```